# Microsoft Sync Framework - How to reprovision a table (or entire scope) after schema changes?

Tags: sql-server, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I have already setup syncing with Microsoft Sync Framework, and now I need to add fields to a table.
How do I re-provision the databases?

The setup is exceedingly simple:

- Two SQL Express 2008 servers
- The scope includes the entire database
- Using Microsoft Sync Framework 2.0
- Synchronizing by direct access. Using the standard new `SqlSyncProvider`

Do I make the structural changes at both ends? Or do I only change one server and let Sync Framework somehow propagate the change?

Do I need to delete the `_tracking` tables and/or the stored procedures? How about the triggers?

Has anyone been using the Sync Framework? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I posted my own answer on my blog http://myazurejourney.blogspot.com/

It has a few step, and it's definitely a hack. But it works.

check it out. tell me what you think

Comment: An important advantage to only re-provisioning the tables that you alter is that you keep all of the MetaData for the scope and all of the other tables participating in the scope

Answer (score 0):

remove the scope and re-provision... use this code to remove a scope

```
private void RemoveScope(SqlConnection Conn, bool ShowAlert)
{
    foreach (var table in _settings.TablesToSync)
    {
        SqlCommand dropTracking = new SqlCommand(@"
            IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[" + table.Key + @"_tracking]') AND type in (N'U'))
            DROP TABLE [dbo].[" + table.Key + "_tracking]", Conn);
        dropTracking.ExecuteNonQuery();

        SqlCommand dropTriggers = new SqlCommand(@"
            IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[" + table.Key + @"_delete_trigger]'))
            DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[" + table.Key + @"_delete_trigger];

            IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[" + table.Key + @"_insert_trigger]'))
            DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[" + table.Key + @"_insert_trigger];

            IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[" + table.Key + @"_update_trigger]'))
            DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[" + table.Key + @"_update_trigger];
        ", Conn);
        dropTriggers.ExecuteNonQuery();

        SqlCommand dropStoredProc = new SqlCommand(@"
            IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[" + table.Key + @"_delete]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
            DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[" + table.Key + @"_delete];

            IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[" + table.Key + @"_deletemetadata]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
            DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[" + table.Key + @"_deletemetadata];

            IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[" + table.Key + @"_insert]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
            DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[" + table.Key + @"_insert];

            IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[" + table.Key + @"_insertmetadata]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
            DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[" + table.Key + @"_insertmetadata];

            IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[" + table.Key + @"_selectchanges]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
            DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[" + table.Key + @"_selectchanges];

            IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[" + table.Key + @"_selectrow]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
            DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[" + table.Key + @"_selectrow];

            IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[" + table.Key + @"_update]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
            DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[" + table.Key + @"_update];

            IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[" + table.Key + @"_updatemetadata]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
            DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[" + table.Key + @"_updatemetadata];
        ", Conn);
        dropStoredProc.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    SqlCommand getScopeGuid = new SqlCommand(@"
            USE [" + Conn.Database + @"]
            SELECT scope_config_id FROM scope_info WHERE scope_name = '" + _settings.ScopeName + "'", Conn);

    var reader = getScopeGuid.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        reader.Read();

        var id = reader.GetGuid(0);

        reader.Close();

        SqlCommand deleteScope = new SqlCommand(@"
                DELETE FROM scope_info WHERE scope_config_id = '" + id + @"';
                DELETE FROM scope_config WHERE config_id = '" + id + @"';
            ", Conn);
        deleteScope.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    if(ShowAlert)
        MessageBox.Show("Scope has been removed");
}
```

Comment: B"H

Yup you've got the basic idea of how to totally get sync MetaData out of your database.

First of all I want to point out to be careful. If you have multiple scopes pointing to the same tables. The code you presented will delete the triggers, sprocs, etc. shared between scopes and when you try to execute your other scope you'll be in trouble.

I am surprised that a function like that is not included in the framework. Maybe as the "community" we can put together a utility that would include simple helper methods like this one and the one I posted on my blog.

Comment: Next I want to comment a bit on your programming:
1. you use an anti-pattern of passing a parameter to show a message box. If the caller knows enough to pass that parameter then it should just be handling the UI on its own and just show the message box after this function returns.
2. Conn is a funny choice for a parameter when you magically get the _settings object. I would think to do it the other way around if at all - settings should be the parameter (that is what you are working on) and Conn should be accessed through IOC or member variable.

Comment: 3. Why "USE [" + Conn.Database + @"]"? If you are getting the name of the database from the connection. Then that must be the current database of the connection. So that is totally superfluous.

Comment: 4. I would recommend that you execute the getScopeGuid and deletes as one command without the extra round-trip. Just use a TSQL variable (I have an example of that in my re-provision code that I posted on my blog). Or at the very least, you can use ExecuteScalar instead of all the piping code of opening and closing a reader.

Comment: 1. MSFx version 2.1 includes a function to deprovision

Comment: 2. i know im programming in an anti-pattern fashion, sorry about that.

Comment: 3. the USE [Database] is a legacy from the SQL script... could/should be removed

Answer (score 0):

I've used Montago's solution, but converted it to SQL code which did the job for me. Be free to use it, I hope it helps you :)

```
USE DatabaseName
GO

DECLARE @sqlDrop VARCHAR(1000)
SET @sqlDrop = 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #table# WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(''#name#'')) DROP #what# #name#'
DECLARE @sqlCommand VARCHAR(1000)

DECLARE @id INT
SET @id = 0
DECLARE @name SYSNAME
DECLARE @prev INT

WHILE 1 = 1
   BEGIN
      /* find traces of synchronization */

      -- to be sure that id changed
      SET @prev = @id

      -- get the next table
      SELECT TOP 1
             @id = object_id,
             @name = name
        FROM sys.tables
       WHERE object_id > @id
       ORDER BY object_id

      -- confirm that there is next table
      IF @id = @prev
         BREAK

      /* remove traces of synchronization */

      -- remove table
      SET @sqlCommand = @sqlDrop
      SET @sqlCommand = REPLACE(@sqlCommand, '#table#', 'sys.tables')
      SET @sqlCommand = REPLACE(@sqlCommand, '#name#', @name + '_tracking')
      SET @sqlCommand = REPLACE(@sqlCommand, '#what#', 'TABLE')
      EXEC (@sqlCommand)

      -- remove triggers
      SET @sqlCommand = @sqlDrop
      SET @sqlCommand = REPLACE(@sqlCommand, '#table#', 'sys.triggers')
      SET @sqlCommand = REPLACE(@sqlCommand, '#name#', @name + '_delete_trigger')
      SET @sqlCommand = REPLACE(@sqlCommand, '#what#', 'TRIGGER')
      EXEC (@sqlCommand)
      SET @sqlCommand = REPLACE(@sqlCommand, '_delete_trigger', '_insert_trigger')
      EXEC (@sqlCommand)
      SET @sqlCommand = REPLACE(@sqlCommand, '_insert_trigger', '_update_trigger')
      EXEC (@sqlCommand)

      -- remove stored procedures
      SET @sqlCommand = @sqlDrop
      SET @sqlCommand = REPLACE(@sqlCommand, '#table#', 'sys.procedures')
      SET @sqlCommand = REPLACE(@sqlCommand, '#name#', @name + '_delete')
      SET @sqlCommand = REPLACE(@sqlCommand, '#what#', 'PROCEDURE')
      EXEC (@sqlCommand)
      SET @sqlCommand = REPLACE(@sqlCommand, '_delete', '_deletemetadata')
      EXEC (@sqlCommand)
      SET @sqlCommand = REPLACE(@sqlCommand, '_deletemetadata', '_insert')
      EXEC (@sqlCommand)
      SET @sqlCommand = REPLACE(@sqlCommand, '_insert', '_insertmetadata')
      EXEC (@sqlCommand)
      SET @sqlCommand = REPLACE(@sqlCommand, '_insertmetadata', '_selectchanges')
      EXEC (@sqlCommand)
      SET @sqlCommand = REPLACE(@sqlCommand, '_selectchanges', '_selectrow')
      EXEC (@sqlCommand)
      SET @sqlCommand = REPLACE(@sqlCommand, '_selectrow', '_update')
      EXEC (@sqlCommand)
      SET @sqlCommand = REPLACE(@sqlCommand, '_update', '_updatemetadata')
      EXEC (@sqlCommand)
      SET @sqlCommand = REPLACE(@sqlCommand, '_updatemetadata', '_bulkdelete')
      EXEC (@sqlCommand)
      SET @sqlCommand = REPLACE(@sqlCommand, '_bulkdelete', '_bulkinsert')
      EXEC (@sqlCommand)
      SET @sqlCommand = REPLACE(@sqlCommand, '_bulkinsert', '_bulkupdate')
      EXEC (@sqlCommand)

   END

-- remove scope and schema tables
SET @sqlCommand = @sqlDrop
SET @sqlCommand = REPLACE(@sqlCommand, '#table#', 'sys.tables')
SET @sqlCommand = REPLACE(@sqlCommand, '#name#', 'schema_info')
SET @sqlCommand = REPLACE(@sqlCommand, '#what#', 'TABLE')
EXEC (@sqlCommand)
SET @sqlCommand = REPLACE(@sqlCommand, 'schema_info', 'scope_config')
EXEC (@sqlCommand)
SET @sqlCommand = REPLACE(@sqlCommand, 'scope_config', 'scope_info')
EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```

This, as you can see goes through all the tables and try to find traces of syncing. You just need to change the database name (first line).
Also, if you want to be safer with what you delete, use this code to find tables:

```
  -- get the next table
  SELECT TOP 1
         @id = object_id,
         @name = REPLACE(name, '_tracking', '')
    FROM sys.tables
   WHERE object_id > @id
     AND name LIKE '%_tracking'
   ORDER BY object_id
```

This will only look for tables that are actually being synchronized

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script:

```
declare @SQL varchar(max);
set @SQL='';
select @SQL += ' IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].[schema_info]'') AND type in (N''U'')) ' +  
               ' DROP TABLE [dbo].[schema_info]; ' +
               ' IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].[scope_config]'') AND type in (N''U'')) ' + 
               ' DROP TABLE [dbo].[scope_config]; ' +
               ' IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].[scope_info]'') AND type in (N''U'')) ' + 
               ' DROP TABLE [dbo].[scope_info]; ' +
               ' IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].[' +  name  + '_tracking]'') AND type in (N''U'')) ' + 
               ' DROP TABLE [dbo].[' +  name  + '_tracking]; ' +
               ' IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].[' + name + '_delete_trigger]'')) ' +
               ' DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[' + name + '_delete_trigger];' +
               ' IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].[' + name + '_insert_trigger]'')) ' +
               ' DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[' + name + '_insert_trigger]; ' +
               ' IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].[' + name + '_update_trigger]'')) ' +
               ' DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[' + name + '_update_trigger]; ' +
               ' IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].[' + name + '_delete]'') AND type in (N''P'', N''PC'')) ' +
               ' DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[' + name + '_delete]; ' +
               ' IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].[' + name + '_deletemetadata]'') AND type in (N''P'', N''PC'')) ' +
               ' DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[' + name + '_deletemetadata]; ' +
               ' IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].[' + name + '_insert]'') AND type in (N''P'', N''PC'')) ' +
               ' DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[' + name + '_insert]; ' + 
               ' IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].[' + name + '_insertmetadata]'') AND type in (N''P'', N''PC'')) ' +
               ' DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[' + name + '_insertmetadata]; ' +
               ' IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].[' + name + '_selectchanges]'') AND type in (N''P'', N''PC'')) ' +
               ' DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[' + name + '_selectchanges]; ' +
               ' IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].[' + name + '_selectrow]'') AND type in (N''P'', N''PC'')) ' +
               ' DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[' + name + '_selectrow]; ' +
               ' IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].[' + name + '_update]'') AND type in (N''P'', N''PC'')) ' +
               ' DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[' + name + '_update]; ' +
               ' IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].[' + name + '_updatemetadata]'') AND type in (N''P'', N''PC'')) ' +
               ' DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[' + name + '_updatemetadata]; ' +
               ' IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].[' + name + '_BulkType]'') AND type in (N''P'', N''PC'')) ' +
               ' DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[' + name + '_BulkType]; ' +
               ' IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].[' + name + '_bulkinsert]'') AND type in (N''P'', N''PC'')) ' +
               ' DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[' + name + '_bulkinsert]; ' +
               ' IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].[' + name + '_bulkupdate]'') AND type in (N''P'', N''PC'')) ' +
               ' DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[' + name + '_bulkupdate]; ' +
               ' IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].[' + name + '_bulkdelete]'') AND type in (N''P'', N''PC'')) ' +
               ' DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[' + name + '_bulkdelete]; '              
from sysobjects
where type = 'U'

--select @SQL
EXEC(@SQL)
GO
```